# Changing user params to include their username

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To view a user page on my app you have to enter their id `/user/2`.

How can I make it so that it uses their `username` in the params instead of id value for user show page? I would like it to be `/user/username` or `/username`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Routes:

```
  get 'signup' => 'users#new'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  get 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  get 'edit' => 'users#edit'
  get "/profile/:id" => "users#show"
  get "profile/:id/settings" => 'users#edit'
  get 'settings/:id' => 'users#settings'

 resources :users do
    resources :messages do
      post :new
      collection do
        get :askout
      end
    end
    collection do
        get :trashbin
        post :empty_trash
     end
  end
```

Users controller:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])    
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience the easiest way I've found to do this is to use the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem. There is a `to_param` method in ActiveRecord that you can set to define what a model's route id is going to be, but if the attribute you want to use is not already URL friendly it will become very complicated.  Assuming your usernames contain no spaces or other URL "unfriendly" characters, you could do something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def to_param
    username
  end
  ...
end
```

But make sure in your controller you then find users by their username.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def set_user
    @user = User.find_by(username: params[:id])
  end
end
```

Note that if the value in `to_param` is not EXACTLY what the value in the database is, finding your object again is going to be more difficult.  For example, if you wanted to use `name.parameterize` to set have URLs like `/users/john-doe` when your actual name attribute is `John Doe`, you'll have to find a way to consistently "deparameterize" your parameter. Or, you can create a new database column that contains a unique parameterized string of the attribute you want in the url (called a slug). That's why I use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id).  It handles your slugs semi-automatically.

As for routing your users to `/username`, you have several options:

- `get ':id', to: 'users#show', as: 'show'`
- `resources 'users', path: '/'`

Just make sure you put these routes at the end of your routes file.  That way if you try to get to your `index` action on `SomeOtherModelsController` by going to `/some_other_model` it's not going to try to find you a user with username "some_other_model".

Comment: Thanks. Your post was detailed and extremely helpful! This fits my requirements since I only need friendly urls for the profiles.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

i. You can use the gem [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

ii. Add to_param method to your user model and return username

```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     def to_param
       username
     end
   end
```

With this option you will have to replace

```
   User.find(params[:id])
```

with

```
   User.find_by_username(params[:id])
```

Comment: Thanks for looking to assist!

Answer (score 1):

[**Slugged Routes**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug)

What you're asking about is something called "slugged" routes.

These are when you use a `slug` in your application to determine which objects to load, rather than using a [`primary_key`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/PrimaryKey/ClassMethods.html#method-i-primary_key) (usually an `id`)

To handle this in Rails, you'll need to be able to support the `slug` in the backend, and the best way to do this is to use the [`friendly_id` gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id):

---

**`friendly_id`**

Id highly recommend using the `friendly_id` gem for this:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   friendly_id :username, use: [:slugged, :finders]
end
```

The `friendly_id` gem does 2 things extremely well:

> 1. It "upgrades" the ActiveRecord `find` method to use the `slug` column, as well as the primary key
> 2. It  allows you to reference the slugged object directly in your link helpers

It basically means you can do this:

```
<%= link_to user.name, user %>
```

If using the `friendly_id` gem, this will *automatically* populate with the `slug` attribute of your table

Further, it allows you to do something else - it gives you the ability to treat the `params[:id]` option in the backend in exactly the same way as before - providing the functionality you require.

---

**Routes**

You should clear up your routes as follows:

```
#config/routes.rb
 get "/profile/:id" => "users#show"
 get "profile/:id/settings" => 'users#edit'
 get 'settings/:id' => 'users#settings'

 resources :sessions, only: [:new, :destroy], path_names: { new: "login", destroy: "logout" }
 resources :users, path_names: { new: "signup" } do
    resources :messages do
      post :new
      collection do
        get :askout
      end
    end
    collection do
        get :trashbin
        post :empty_trash
     end
  end
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation and taking the time out to assist!

Answer (score -1):

Make a new attribute on your User model.  You can call it what you want, but usually it's called "slug".

```
rails g migration AddSlugToUser slug:string
rake db:migrate
```

Store in it a "url friendly" version of the username.  the parameterize method is good for that.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
before_save :create_slug

def create_slug
  self.slug = self.name.parameterize
end
```

In the same model create a `to_param` method which will automatically include slug in links (instead of the user id)

```
def to_param
  slug
end
```

Finally, where you do `User.find` replace it with `find_by_slug`

```
@user = User.find_by_slug(params[:id])
```