# Username as parameter with blacklist validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the User model with the username as paramenter instead of the id. So currently I have this in my route:

```
resources :u, param: :username, :as => :user, :controller => :user
```

But now I would like to access the user profile via `/:username`, but I see a problem with it. I have routes like `/login`, `/logout`, `/settings`. A user can change his username. Now how can I handle, so that the user cannot have usernames like this routes above?

Comment: Pro tip: use `resources :users, path: '/u', param: :username` to take advantage of the default routing to the controller and route naming.

Comment: @coreyward, I think this is _not_ a duplicate of the question you linked to. If I understand @Sylnois correctly he's concerned about a user creating an account with a username of `login` so that `/login` would match both `/:username` (leading to the profile) and `/login` (leading to the login screen). @Sylnois you need to add a validator to your `User` model ([`exclusion`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#exclusion) seems to be a good fit). Ideally, your models would query routing for path names it should avoid but I don't have an idea how to best do that right now.

Comment: @sylnois What you want is a bad idea. There will be more problems that you are not even know about yet. Make the user profile path like  `/profile/:username` or `/users/:username` or `/u/:username`

Comment: @GregNavis Hmm, I'll re-open, but I think the linked question provides much more consideration than OP has given to the implementation. There are, for example, more challenging implementation details to solve for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing your concern in isolation, you can ensure that conflicting usernames are prohibited using a blacklist.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :username, exclusion: { in: %w{ login logout settings }
end
```

In practice, you will also want to blacklist usernames that can be misleading or convey undue authority. For example, you wouldn't want a user with the username “admin”, “administrator”, or “site_owner” because it could confuse other users.

You can also take advantage of the way Rails prioritizes routes (top down) to ensure that named routes are always given precedence over the user route:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get :login, to: 'sessions#new'
  get '/:username', to: 'users#show'
end 

GET /login #=> sessions#new
GET /foo #=> users#show
```

This enables you to add additional named routes over time that will take over username routes, which is a nice secondary protection.

For more on implementing vanity urls and using usernames in routes (instead of ids), I suggest taking a look at [Changing user params to include their username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168505/changing-user-params-to-include-their-username).

---

Example to read in a file of blacklisted usernames for validation:

```
# app/models/concerns/blacklist.rb
module Blacklist
  def blacklist
    @_blacklist ||= File.readlines(Rails.root.join 'lib', 'blacklist.txt')
  end
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  extend Blacklist
  validates :username, exclusion: { in: blacklist }
end
```

Comment: This answer looks very promising. Is there a way to combine your answer with the given blacklist for usernames: https://github.com/shouldbee/reserved-usernames/blob/master/reserved-usernames.txt?

Comment: @Sylnois Absolutely; assuming you put the blacklist file in your project directory (e.g., at `lib/blacklisted-usernames.txt`) you can read it in as an array of lines (names) and hand that to the validator, which is expecting an array. I'll add an example, but it's largely out of scope.

Comment: Thank you very much. This looks very promising.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options here. The first is as suggested in the comments to your question: to have a list of excluded usernames and validate the user's username against that list before allowing them to create their account. [Here's an example of one such list you could use](https://github.com/shouldbee/reserved-usernames/blob/master/reserved-usernames.txt).

The second is simpler: make the users route live at something like `/u/username`, instead of just `/username`.